# .py to .exe with images used in the python code

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, executable

I have a file called main.py. This is in a folder called "project" which also contains some images that main.py reads. How do I turn this into a .exe? I tried using auto-py-to-exe, but that does not bundle the images into the .exe, which prompts an error.

If it is important, I am on macOS.

Comment: You can try PyInstaller: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`. Read more here https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/

Comment: @MatanItzhak It is saying I have reached the maximum recursion depth

Comment: Please add the relevant traceback to the question along with the steps you've tried. That way it would be much easier to help you overcome this problem.